# How to list pages in a category as bullet points in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm using MediaWiki and I would like to list pages with a specific tag in alphabetical order.

I.e. If the following 5 pages have the category "Backup" I would get a list similar to

- Printing
- Programming
- Remote Access
- Remote Sound
- Smartcard

`DynamicPageList` with

```
<DynamicPageList>
category             = Backup
</DynamicPageList>
```

gives me what I am looking for, but not in alphabetical order based on page title.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution

```
{{#dpl:category=Backup|format=,*,[[%PAGE%]]\n,}}
```